# Column gap is not working in react which i am creating usinggutter in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

```html
<section className=" py-5 bg-light">
  <div className="container ">
    <div className="row  gx-4 gy-4 d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div className="col-lg-12 ">
        <h1 className="fw-bold py-5 ps-0 ">Modules</h1>
      </div>

      <div className=" col-lg-6 col-md-6   px-3 bg-white rounded-5 ">
        <div className="">
          <h3 className="py-3">Administration</h3>
        </div>
        <p className="">

        </p>
      </div>

      <div className=" col-lg-6 col-md-6  bg-white rounded-5 ">
        <div className="">
          <h3 className="py-3"> Student</h3>
        </div>
        <p>

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I was attempting to achieve a layout similar to the one depicted in the image. Essentially, I aimed to create two div boxes containing paragraphs within them. Ideally, these div boxes would be arranged in a row with a maximum of two boxes, and on smaller screens, only one box per row. However, despite utilizing gutter settings, I encountered an issue where the space between the boxes was not being displayed horizontally (in the x-direction), while it was being displayed vertically (in the y-direction). I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

**This is the type of column gap I'm aiming for:**

[image: Image of the type of column gap I'm aiming for]